# CSS ignored when <!DOCTYPE html> is added

Tags: php, css, html, doctype

I am quite bothered by this as I didn't find any solution anywhere.

I started writing some simple web, using just HTML and PHP.
When I found out, that I forgot to add DOCTYPE declaration, half the way, I decideD to just add it to the top of the page. When I did that my CSS stopped apPlying.

So far I have this:

```
<?php
session_start();

require "../frequent_functions.php";
F_check_login();


?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>
            Velká Hra
        </title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.php" />
        <?php 
            echo include_in_header();
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="news_banner">
            zde se budou zobrazovat novinky
        </div>
        <div class="header_page">
            Toto je hlavička stránky
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="form">
                <form method="POST" action="procedures/accept_code.php">
                    <div class="form_segment">
                        Unikátní kód z ukořistěného kolíčku: <br />
                        <input type="text" name="peg_code" placeholder="Vložte kód z kolíčku" /> 
                    </div>
                </form
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
            echo $_SESSION['UserID'];



        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I checked browser caching, hard reset, access rights to files. I have no idea what is wrong.

Those PHP functions do not generate content, except this function:

```
function include_in_header() {
    return '<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pirata+One" rel="stylesheet">';
}
```

but that shall not affect anything.. or does it? I am clueless.

EDIT 1:
This is not duplicate. Please read my question and read those to which you are refering. I have read them, they do not answer my question.

Removing the Doctype solves the problem. But lack of doctype itself is a problem, as described in other questions.

Comment: Are you sure it is `styles.php` and not `styles.css`? You can also try to move the doctype declaration below the PHP closing tag (I don't think it will help you, but you might as well try it).

Comment: https://w3c.github.io/html/links.html#ref-for-quirks-mode%E2%91%A0

Comment: The naming of files is okay. Also, if you use PHP, the CSS will not apply when it does not have the *.php suffix although I dont know exactly why. I tried to change those to .css but nothing changed.

Comment: Okay, so when i tried to change the suffixes for the second time, it started working. So probably it was somehow about the suffix.

Comment: Well I would really like to add an explanation to what really happened, but some ignorant arabic-named individuum marked my question as duplicate... so whatever.